# vector range constructor with updated data from another vector

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

Is it possible to create `vector< pair <int,int> >` using range constructor from another `vector<int>`?
eg.

```
vector < pair <int, int>>
```

in that first is `vector<int>` data and second is index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to transform your original vector, so for instance, with mutable lambdas:

```
int main () {
    std::vector<int> foo{1, 2, 3, 4};

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> bar;

    int i = 0;
    std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::back_inserter(bar), [i](int x) mutable {return std::make_pair(x, i++);});    
}
```

Range constructor will not work because you need to transform your operators, so the `transform` algorithm is the best option. You can wrap it in a function, and then it's the same number of lines than the range constructor.